# Second monitor connected with DisplayPort (male) to HDMI (female) adapter, isn't always detected, why?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I've recently changed my graphic card and this new graphic card have 1 HDMI port and 3 display ports, the thing is that my monitors only have HDMI ports, so for the first one, there is no problem, I use my HDMI cable, and it works well, but for my second monitor, I've bought a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter, so I plug the adapter to the card's display port, and then the HDMI cable to the adapter and to my second monitor.

The issue is, my second screen is not always detected by my computer. I have dual boot with Windows and Arch Linux, and it happens with both OSes, so I have to unplug and replug the adapter, sometimes, multiple times and, often I have to plug the adapter to another DisplayPort, for my screen to be detected, because if I use the same port. It's not detected, doesn't matter how many times I replug the adapter.

What is disturbing it that the monitor can be used during boot with grub, and during log in, but when I log in, It turns black, and my primary monitor (The one without the adapter), takes the relay. It never happens the other way around. Sometimes, I have nothing to do, the monitors are on and works well with nothing to be done.

- **My graphic card is**: Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2060 D6 6G (Rev 2.0) (6 Go)
- **DisplayPort to HDMI adapter**: Adaptateur DisplayPort 1.2 vers HDMI 4K 60 Hz - StarTech

Comment: This should work, so there might be a problem with the adapter or the cable.